# Question on the $arg$ function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

We recently came across $arg$ in our lectures:

$\arg\colon \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathopen] -\pi, \pi]$,

$ z \to \arg(z)$, so $z=|z|e^{i{\arg(z)}}$

First question: why is the function bounded by $\mathopen]-\pi,\pi]$, surely it could also be bounded by $\mathopen]0,2\pi]$ or even by $[0,2\pi\mathclose[$. I do not understand the significance of its bound as it is periodical in any case?

Second question: I've had a look at the following problem: Solve $z^3=-i$, where $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Since $\arg(-i) \in \mathopen]-\pi,\pi]$ we are required to say $-i=e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}+2ki\pi}=z^3$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore, $z_{k}=e^{\frac{-i\frac{\pi}{2}+2ki\pi}{3}}$, $k=0,1,2$

Using this we get:

$z_{0}=e^{\frac{-i\pi}{6}}$, $\arg(z_{0})=\frac{-\pi}{6}$, which lies in $\mathopen]-\pi,\pi]$

$z_{1}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$, which is correct as arg also lies in the range

Now the problem arrives, as:

$z_{2}= e^{i\frac{7}{6}\pi}$ and $\arg(z_{2})=\frac{7}{6}\pi$, which does not lie in the range $\mathopen]-\pi,\pi]$. Does this mean $z_{2}$ is not a solution to the problem? Or, is $z_{2}$ still as solution, as it is periodical and $\arg(z_{2})=\arg(z_{2})+2(-1)\pi=-\frac{5}{6}\pi \in \mathopen]-\pi,\pi]$. Am I missing something, or just leading myself astray? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to your first question -- this is simply a matter of convention (and I do not think that the convention you gave is universal). As you noted, the periodicity would allow arg to be defined to have values on any half-open interval of length $2\pi$ -- in order for arg to be a well-defined function, we must merely choose one such interval arbitrarily.

As to your second question -- if we take $z = e^{-\frac56\pi}$, $z^3 = (e^{-\frac56\pi})^3 = e^{-\frac52\pi} = e^{-2\pi}e^{-\frac12\pi} = e^{-\frac12\pi} = -i$. Since $z = e^{-\frac56\pi}$ satisfies the equation, I do not think we should discount it. So yes, sometimes we will need to take advantage of the periodicity to adjust our argument so it falls in the desired range.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to question 1:

Yes, there is nothing particularly special about the choice $(-\pi,\pi]$, and in many conventions, $[0,2\pi)$ is used for the range of arguments.

Answer to question 2:

$z_2=\exp\left(i\frac76\pi\right)$ *is* a solution, since $$e^{i\frac76\pi}\equiv e^{i\frac76\pi-2\pi i}=e^{-i\frac56\pi}$$So the answer that you'd be expected to give is this one, since its argument lies in the correct range. However, this does not mean that the solution with $\arg=\frac76\pi$ is not a solution to the equation - it is, and it is the exact same number as the one with $\arg=-\frac56\pi$. You can see this by computing $$\cos\left(\frac76\pi\right)+i\sin\left(\frac76\pi\right)=\cos\left(-\frac56\pi\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac56\pi\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

The convention that $\arg z$ has range $]-\pi,\pi]$ corresponds to the convention that the cut to form the Riemann surface for $\sqrt{z}$ is along the negative real axis; and the convention that the cut to form the Riemann surfsce for $\log z$ is along the negative real axis.

With these matching conventions, we have
$$
\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{|z|}\;e^{i(\arg z)/2}
\\
\log z = \log |z| + i \arg z
$$